# Custom map for my android app

Tags: android, mapping, map-directions

I want to create a custom map for my app.
the things i want are:

1. it will be a custom map designed by us for a event location(not google map).
2. all the locations will be displayed on the map like google markers.
3. just like google map i want users to select a location and get direction from his/her current location to selected destination within that area(my main concern).

Are there any possible solutions to this? Any links, suggestions to start with please let me know.

This is very imp. for me..thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org) project. They have all the components you need but it is not going to be a simple task for an area of any size

Comment: thanx hardillb..ill look into it.